# TDD: Does it get in the way of good API design?

Tags: api, tdd

I've never written TDD code, but I've seen a decent amount of discussion about it here on SO.  My biggest concern with it is that it seems like general good API design (for flexibility, ease of use, simplicity of interface, and performance) takes a back seat sometimes to making code mockable, ultra-modular beyond what is necessary for any API use case, etc.  For example, TDD proponents often suggest that things be passed in as parameters that, from an API abstraction perspective, the method being called should "just know", or that classes and methods be factored in a way that makes testing easy, which is not necessarily the way that relates best to the problem domain.

To people more experienced with both TDD and API design:  Do you find that TDD often gets in the way of good API design?  If so, how do you counter this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been using TDD for several years now and I find that it drives an API design towards a more usable design by providing you with two different clients for the API from the start; you have production code and test code both of which want to drive the API in different ways.

It's true that sometimes I add things for the sake of making it easier to test the API but I almost always find that things that I think I'm putting in just for testability's sake are actually very useful for monitoring purposes. So, for example, a `FooAllocator` might end up with an optional constructor argument which is a monitoring interface (`IMonitorFooAllocations`) which is very useful for mocking out during testing to enable me to take a peek inside but which also tends to be very useful when you suddenly find that you have to expose some allocation metrics to the rest of the world whilst in production. I now tend to think of the extra bits that I might want to add to enable easy testing in terms of their dual use for optional production monitoring. I generally write server code and being able to expose the internals of things as perfmon counters is VERY useful...

Likewise you're correct to say that often the objects that makes up an API might take some other objects explicitly rather than reaching out and getting them from a known place but this is a good thing. Trust me, once you get used to dealing with explicit dependencies you wont want to go back to having to dig through class after class to work out how and why your `Widgets` are accessing active directory when there's no hint in the API that they would want to do such a thing. Also it's often the case that you break open these dependency relationships during design and testing and then hide them again as you put all of the pieces together. You still 'parameterize from above' but more often than not an API's object model might mean that you never really see the 'above' as a user of the API. You end up with one place to configure the API with the things that it needs and often this looks no different to how it would have looked if you had a mass of singletons and globals and hidden dependencies.

But remember, TDD is a tool, when it doesn't fit don't use it.

Answer (score 33):

No, I find that TDD generally *encourages* good design. Things which are easily testable are often easy to use in production too... because when coming up with a test, you think, "What would I like to do next?" and then make it work.

When practising TDD you are forced to think through the 'use cases' for an API, how the programmer is going to use the classes/methods and you will end up with a very usable framework.  If you have to create a hundred `FooFactory` and `BarAuthenticator`s, or the API is becoming 'ultra modular' like you say, you will likely pick up on that while writing your test code and think about how to simplify it.

As for parameters and dependency injection - I usually find that dependencies become a lot clearer using TDD. They're usually constructor arguments rather than method arguments, but making it clear that an API implementation needs an authenticator, a source of randomness etc. is useful in understanding what it's doing. You can be sure that the code isn't going to hit the network or a remote database somewhere because it's hiding these things in its implementation. These kind of hidden details are what makes an API hard to use in a test environment.

Note that when dependencies are part of the constructor call, it's not part of the interface that class may implement - the dependencies within an interface are usually hidden, but TDD means that the *implementation* exposes them in an obvious way.

A good source of information about dependency injection and TDD can be found on the [Google Testing Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/). Pay particular attention to the posts by [Miško Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/) or watch some of his videos on Youtube: [Don't Look For Things](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) and [more](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Misko+Hevery&search_type=&aq=f).

Comment: But this is requiring the user of an API to specify dependencies that are implementation details.  The user of an API should only have to care what the API does, not how it does it.

Comment: No, it's getting the user to inject dependencies because that's what the class needs. And if the class goes out and grabs stuff itself, you have inherently untestable and inflexible code.

Comment: @dsimcha: If the API of a given system requires the dependencies, it will do so with TDD or not.  You are not exposing implementation details, but exposing dependencies.  There is a big difference.

Comment: @dsimcha: You need to distinguish between what creates an instance of the interface (which will need to provide the dependencies) and what *uses* the instance (which doesn't need to care).

Comment: But I still maintain two very important points:

1.  The design of an API should reflect the problem domain.
2.  The dependencies may be implementation details from the perspective of the problem domain.

When I say interface, I mean API user interface, not object-oriented interface.  The user of an API should not have to specify details that have no meaning in the context of the problem domain, including dependencies.

Comment: In other words, making a user explicitly specify all dependencies leads to boilerplate code.  Making a user write boilerplate is an absolute no-no in API design.

Comment: @dsimcha: Where do you expect this boilerplate code to be? With dependency injection there's very little of it - you get testable code with mockable dependencies instead of hard-coded ones. It's a win-win situation. For someone who has never used TDD, you seem remarkably convinced that it's going to result in a bad API...

Comment: dsimcha - I think you're missing the point of dependency injection.  All the boilerplate code is supposed to be in the API.  However, key implementation details which may be subject to change later down the road - for instance, let's say someone figures out a way of reverse engineering MD5 hashes, if a user API hardcodes the MD5 dependency then your API will need patching, however, if the API uses dependency injection to set the hashing algorithm, then it's just a case of pushing in a different hashing mechanism.  The rest of the boilerplate code remains unchanged.

Comment: The boilerplate code is the need to explicitly specify where the dependencies are coming from, even if there's only one de facto standard place where they would come from in any scenario other than mocking/testing.

Comment: @dsimcha: Depending on your DI framework, you may be able to specify that as an attribute on the interface. You can with Guice, for example - basically, it means "By default, implement this interface with this class." If you *really* want to, you can give the class a constructor *without* the dependencies and get it to create them and call the parameterful constructor - but I don't generally like doing that. I also think it's a mistake when you're designing an API to *assume* there's only going to be one real dependency implementation.

Answer (score 14):

TDD *is* an API design technique.  Every time you write a unit test, you are either creating an API for the first time, or using a previously created API.  Each one of those tests lets you "feel" how easy or difficult the API is to use.  Each new test forces you to consider the API from a new point of view.  There can hardly be a better way to design APIs than to exhaustively use them the way TDD forces you to.

Indeed, this is the reason that TDD is considered a *design* technique rather than a testing technique.  When you practice TDD, you do not design your APIs in a vacuum.  You design them *by using them*!

Answer (score 12):

TDD leads to [emergent design](http://xprogramming.com/xpmag/expemergentdesign) which ultimately produces a very usable and extensible API. TDD isn't about testing. It's about creating seams in your code that you can use to add behavior as you discover more about your project.

Comment: Darn all you guys posting mere seconds before me. :-)  Michael, maybe adding a reference (e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-eaed2/index.html) for the "emergent design" claim would be helpful.  I haven't vetted that particular one... maybe you can find one more suitable.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I added a link to an article by Ron Jeffries

Answer (score 7):

Most of the things you have listed as disadvantages of TDD are considered by many to be elements of *good* design.

If particular note the idea of something being passed in instead of something the method should "just know" - the latter often leading to singletons or other anti-cohesive designs.

While it may be true that you may end up with a design where some aspects are *only* there to support testability this is not necessarily a bad thing.

As a rule, though, if you have to rethink your design to make it testable you will general arrive at a design that is *better* in terms of cohesiveness and fitness for purpose - while still being flexible in the sense that it can easily be changed to whatever your future needs are through refactoring because you have the tests there to give you the confidence to make changes quickly.

Answer (score 6):

I use TDD and think it works well with respect to API construction, but I think that APIs, especially ones that you expose to external customers, are an area in which you need a little bit more upfront design than typical when using TDD.  TDD relies as heavily on refactoring as it does on test-first.  With an API, you don't always have the luxury of both refactoring your method signatures AND keeping a clean design.  If you aren't careful about designing your interface upfront you can find yourself with an ugly interface that supports multiple methods doing very similar things just to keep backwards compatibility with your existing API while at the same time moving your design forward.

If I have an API that I know I will be exposing to external users, I generally take more time to think about the signature and get it as close to "right" as I can before starting the development process.  I also expose it early and often to my customers to get feedback on it so that we converge as quickly as possible to a stable interface.  Refactoring behind the scenes to improve the implementation without changes to the interface is not so much a problem, but I want to get a stable interface quickly and am willing to invest more upfront to get it.

Answer (score 4):

With traditional API design, it's easy to build yourself into a corner: You can end up with an API that has lots of hidden dependencies (like class A needs B needs C needs D and if you change the order in which the classes are initialized, things start to break).

TDD makes sure you that separate pieces stay separate. It also allows you to see your API from a very unusual perspective: As a user/consumer. Your first question is "How do I want to use this?" not "How do I want the API to look like?" The latter can lure you into a hidden trap while the first leads to something which I call "intuitive API": It behaves as expected.

A word of advice: Don't make TDD your religion. It's a tool and some problems can't be solved with some tools. So if TDD doesn't work for you for any reason, then that's OK. Use as much TDD as you like. Don't be fanatic about it. Over the years, you'll find your comfort zone.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [newspeak](http://newspeaklanguage.org/) language work by a.o. Gilad Bracha to see some relevant API and language design.

Answer (score 1):

I agree 100% with the top answers. But really this depends on what you mean by "good API design". TDD leads to testable, modular, working code-- but in the end, the most important aspect of TDD code is the testability.

You will find that it leads to different design than a other processes yield. You will find that testable code may expose a few more bits of its internals than a pure API might expose.

In many cases it may make sense to use TDD to build working code, and then-- as a separate step-- pull out the API. Otherwise you have two forces working somewhat in conflict: a simple API and testable code.

This is a subtle point, though, and overall TDD will provide much better APIs than designing from an ivory tower.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, since you are using your methods thinking as a user by writing your tests, you will spot the issues that your user will come up with as you write it.
In fact, you will end up with a much cleaner and user-friendly interface that what you would have written otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If your API is suffering due to internal requirements of your objects, that's what the facade pattern is for.  Not all objects need to be public.

A lot of the pain points of TDD are, in fact, signs of pain points in the design.  If it's hard to create a class because it requires 18 dependencies to be passed in, the fundamental problem is that the class has too many dependencies and is going to be quite brittle.  It also probably does waaaaaay too much.  The "TDD pain" in this case is a good thing, as it makes the other issues more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

TDD doesn't get in the way of good API design.

Mocking gets in the way of good API design.

The two are not synonymous - I independently started using TDD before others wrote the books on it, simply because it makes clear whether requirements are testable and designs meet a requirement.

However, I think Mocking is bad because it affects the design and implementation and introduces other, artificial requirements. It also exposes internals of an implementation that shouldn't be, and makes the testing brittle. It tests how something is done, rather than what is done.

How to counter it: Use TDD, but don't use mocking.

Answer (score 0):

The point about TDD i sthat we write tests which call the code as we design it.  Consequently we should end up with an extremely usable interface.  Of course it doesn't entirely happen by chance.  We still have to make the right choices.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed that TDD makes for bad API choices at all.

On the contrary, by creating a clear framework in the first place the API is also more clear, and more obvious to its users.